# How to determine the datatype of columns in a csv file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to determine the data type of all the columns in a csv file. The code  is :

```
df = pd.read_csv('accepted.csv')
for name, dtype in df.dtypes.iteritems():
        print("Column Name: ",name," ||| ","Data Type : ", dtype)
```

Now the problem I am facing is that it gives float64 for most of the columns and 0 for some. How can I get the original data type?

Comment: You can check the `dtypes` using `df.dtypes`.

Comment: The “original” data type in a CSV is always a string, since CSV doesn’t contain any type information.

Answer (score 0):

@Gandharv this code is working fine, i got the correct data types for each features
However you can directly view the datatypes using .dtypes() : This returns a Series with the data type of each column.
Why do you need to use for loop for this since we've a function to do it.

Comment: This is the output for column : id , Data Type :  float64 where the data type is actually int

Comment: why dont you use .dtypes() directly